# call to a url error intent cannot find symbol

Tags: android

I´ve got a problem is that cannot call a url.

Mi code in oncreate

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));

        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

[image]

I corrected the error, but get the same problem

Comment: You have a typo : startActivity(itent); instead of intent. Also, please check your imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a just typo mistake in variable name, try this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

You can try this shorter version also

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(intent);
```

See, if it helps.